# Python Keras: An layer output exactly the same thing as input

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, keras-layer, keras-2

I am using Keras to build a Network. During the process, I need a layer, which takes an LSTM input, doing nothing, just output exactly the same as input. i.e. if each input record of LSTM is like [[A_t1, A_t2, A_t3, A_t4, A_t5, A_t6]], I am looking for a layer:

```
model.add(SomeIdentityLayer(x))
```

SomeIdentityLayer(x) will take `[[A_t1, A_t2, A_t3, A_t4, A_t5, A_t6]]` as input and output `[[A_t1, A_t2, A_t3, A_t4, A_t5, A_t6]]`. Is such layer/structure available in Keras? Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For a simpler operation like identity, you can just use a Lambda layer like:

`model.add(Lambda(lambda x: x))`

This will return an output exactly the same as your input.

Comment: You'll want to add `input_shape=your_input_shape` e.g. `model.add(Lambda(lambda x: x, input_shape=x))` if you want this to be the only layer in a network

Comment: any idea about the complexity differences between this and using tf.identity()?

Answer (score 13):

Actually, default `call()` implementation in `Layer` is identity, so you can just use:

```
model.add(Layer())
```

Comment: Do you know which of the two solutions (`Lambda(lambda x: x)` and `Layer()`) is preferable in terms of runtime complexity?

Answer (score 2):

You can use,

```py
layer = tf.keras.layers.Activation('linear')
x = tf.constant([1.0, -1.0, 1.5])
y = layer(x) # output: same as x
```

### Update: 31 Jan 2023

As from `tensorflow==2.12.0` there is support for dedicated layer to simply pass through the input,

```py
layer = tf.keras.layers.Identity() 
x = tf.constant([1.0, -1.0, 1.5])
y = layer(x) # output: same as x
```

Ref: [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Identity)