# Tensorflow training - print multiple losses for one output

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I would like to print all the different losses I have for one output separately.
At the moment it looks like:

```
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 1s/sample - loss: 4.2632
```

The goal is to have a history like:

```
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 1s/sample - loss1: 2.1, loss2: 2.1632
```

I have one output layer out1 and two loss functions loss1 and loss2.

```
def loss1(y_true, y_pred):
    ...
    return ...
```

```
def loss2(y_true, y_pred):
    ...
    return ...
```

When I do

```
model.compile(...)
```

I can either choose to have a single loss function,

```
model.compile(loss=lambda x: loss1(x) + loss2(x))
```

or defining a loss for each output in a dictionary

```
model.compile(loss={'out1': loss1(x), 'out2': loss2(x)})
```

Since I have only one output, this isn't an option for me.
Does anyone know how to print the losses separately when having only one output?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `metrics` argument:

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mae', metrics=['mse'])
```

You will still need to choose one loss to minimize.

Comment: how would it be with two loss functions?

Comment: what do you mean "how would it be"?

Comment: In my question, I pointed out that I have two loss functions. Your answer uses just a single loss function.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to artificially create the same two outputs, and then combine them with weights equal 1. For the sake of concreteness, I wrote the example:

```
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Lambda
from tensorflow.keras.losses import mse, mae
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__':
    train_x = np.random.rand(10000, 200)
    train_y = np.random.rand(10000, 1)

    x_input = Input(shape=(200))
    x = Dense(64)(x_input)
    x = Dense(64)(x)
    x = Dense(1)(x)

    x1 = Lambda(lambda x: x, name='out1')(x)
    x2 = Lambda(lambda x: x, name='out2')(x)

    model = Model(inputs=x_input, outputs=[x1, x2])

    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss={'out1': mse, 'out2': mae}, loss_weights={'out1': 1, 'out2': 1})

    model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=10)
```

Comment: Introducing another dense layer might have a significant impact on the model quality. If they have shared weights, than this is fine. However, having two identical outputs is dirty.

Comment: Ok, I've created dummy identity layers instead. Now it should give the same output

Comment: @DatabaseNewbie I've just checked in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47297779/python-keras-an-layer-output-exactly-the-same-thing-as-input that there are easier ways to implement identity layer.

Comment: @DatabaseNewbie I rewrote my answer and give you an example instead